# List of proper Jeffreys priors?

Tags: bayesian, references, jeffreys-prior, objective-bayes

I know that Jeffreys priors are often improper. In fact, the only proper Jeffreys prior that I know is for the success probability in Bernoulli model (the prior arcsine).

I am curious to know if there are other proper Jeffreys priors, and eventually if there is some list available.

Comment: This [paper by Berger, Bernardo and Sun (2015)](https://www.uv.es/~bernardo/2015BAdiss.pdf) contains a few further examples.

Comment: Thank you very much.